# MongoDb Sort gives Incorrect result with Alphanumeric values

Tags: mongodb

```
 [
   {"name": "Card 1"},
   {"name": "Card 2"},
   {"name": "Card 10"}
 ]
```

MongoDb result with sort by `{ "name": 1 }` is

```
  [ 
    {"name": "Card 1"},
    {"name": "Card 10"},
    {"name": "Card 2"}
  ]
```

How I can correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because, `numbers` in your data are compared as `String`. Hence, you get sorted value as 1, 10, 2 so on.

When you create your collection index, you have to specify collation with various  language-specific rules for comparision. By default, when you create a collection without collation information default value `numericOrdering` is set false -That means numbers are treated as String while comparing.

Therefore, you have to either create index with [**collation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) with `numericOrdering` true or provide such information in query time as below.

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({
  "name": 1
}).collation({
  locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm also facing this problem with lodash, Are you know lodash?